# How does recursively iterating through lists with CDR work with Cons in Scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

Specifically, I have the following function

```
(define (even-odd-filter x . intlist)   
  (if (equal? '() intlist)
      '()
      (if (equal? (modulo x 2) (modulo (car intlist) 2))
          (cons (car intlist) (even-odd-filter x (cdr intlist)))
          (even-odd-filter x (cdr intlist)))))
```

Can someone please explain why this would break on the second iteration?
As far as I know, (car list) is meant to refer to the first element of list, however, in the second recursive call

`(modulo (car int list) 2)`

causes an error as the interpreter believes that `(car intlist)` references the whole list as opposed to the first element of said list.

I am quite lost on this, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is that if you call `(even-odd-filter 5 1 2 3)` it will do 
`(cons 1 (even-odd-filter 5 '(2 3)))` and `intlist` will be `((2 3))` in the second iteration.

To avoid this it's best to use a helper such that only the outer call has rest arguments:

```
(define (even-odd-filter x . intlist)
  (let helper ((intlist intlist))   
    (cond
      ((null? intlist) '())
      ((equal? (modulo x 2) (modulo (car intlist) 2))
       (cons (car intlist) (helper (cdr intlist))))
      (else
       (helper (cdr intlist))))))
```

Another nice thing with this is that `x`, that doesn't change in he iteration isn't passed but used as a free variable. It makes easier to read code. Since you have nested `if` I turned it into `cond` which is for a typical `if-then-else` scenario.

If you really want rest arguments in recursion, you need to use `apply` in each recursive call. This is not very efficient since it most likely will create a new list each iteration:

```
(define (even-odd-filter x . intlist)   
  (if (equal? '() intlist)
      '()
      (if (equal? (modulo x 2) (modulo (car intlist) 2))
          (cons (car intlist) (apply even-odd-filter x (cdr intlist)))
          (apply even-odd-filter x (cdr intlist)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that if you define a function with the syntax:

```
(define (function arg1 . rest-of-args-as-list) body)
```

you should call it always with a certain number of arguments, but not with a list. For instance, assuming you need to operate on a sequence of integers, you can call it in this way:

```
(function 1 2 3 4 5)
```

and inside the body of the function `arg1` will be bound to `1` and `rest-of-args-as-list` will be bound to the list `(2 3 4 5)`.

So in you case, if you call the function: `(even-odd-filter 1 2 3 4 5)`, `x` will be bound to `1`, `intlis`t to `(2 3 4 5)` and in the second iteration, the function will be called as: `(even-odd-filter 1 (3 4 5))` (since `x` is `1` and `cdr` of `(2 3 4 5)` is `(3 4 5)`). 
And calling it in this way will produce the error (in DrRacket):

```
modulo: contract violation
  expected: integer?
  given: '(3 4 5)
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
>
```

How could you solve this problem?

A possibility is to define the function with a single argument which is a list. Here is a rewriting of your function in this way:

```
(define (even-odd-filter intlist)   
  (cond ((equal? '() intlist) '())
        ((equal? '() (cdr intlist)) intlist)
        ((equal? (modulo (car intlist) 2) (modulo (cadr intlist) 2))
         (cons (cadr intlist) (even-odd-filter (cons (car intlist) (cddr intlist)))))
        (else (even-odd-filter (cons (car intlist) (cddr intlist))))))
```